# System of congruent relations using Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

Could someone explain how to use CRT on the following example:
$$x\equiv 7\pmod {17}$$
$$x\equiv 9\pmod {13}$$
$$x\equiv 3\pmod {12}$$

$a_1=7$,  $m_1=17$, $M=2652$, $\frac{M}{m_1}=156$

$a_2=9$, $m_2=13$,             $\frac{M}{m_2}=204$

$a_3=3$, $m_3=12$,             $\frac{M}{m_3}=221$

First equation:
$$x\equiv 7\pmod {17}\Rightarrow 156b_1\equiv 1\pmod {17}\Rightarrow 156 : 17 = 9 (3)\Rightarrow 3b_1\equiv 1\pmod {17}\Rightarrow b_1\equiv 3^{\phi(17)-1}\equiv 3^{15}\equiv ?\pmod {17}$$

$\phi(n)$ is Euler function, and $\phi(17)=16$

I am stuck here. How to find integer $(?)$

Could someone give detailed explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$3^{16}\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ 17\ )$$

and

$$3^{16}=3^{15}\times 3 \equiv 1\equiv 6\times 3\ (\ mod\ 17\ )$$

So, we get $$3^{15}\equiv 6\ (\ mod\ 17\ )$$

by multiplying $3^{15}\times 3\equiv 6\times 3$ by $3^{-1}$